# Succinctly assign names and values simultaneously

Tags: r, assign

I find myself often writing the following two lines.  Is there a succinct alternative?

```
      newObj  <- vals
names(newObj) <- nams

# This works, but is ugly and not necessarily preferred
'names<-'(newObj <- vals, nams)
```

I'm looking for something similar to this (which of course does not work):

```
newObj <- c(nams = vals)
```

Wrapping it up in a function is an option as well, but I am wondering if the functionality might already be present.

*sample data*

```
vals <- c(1, 2, 3)
nams <- c("A", "B", "C")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want the `setNames` function

```
# Your example data
vals <- 1:3
names <- LETTERS[1:3]
# Using setNames
newObj <- setNames(vals, names)
newObj
#A B C 
#1 2 3
```

Answer (score 5):

The `names<-` method often (if not always) copies the object internally. `setNames` is simply a wrapper for `names<-`,

If you want to assign names and values succinctly in code and memory, then the `setattr` function, from either the `bit` or `data.table` packages will do this by reference (no copying)

eg

```
library(data.table) # or library(bit)
setattr(vals, 'names', names)
```

Perhaps slightly less succinct, but you could write yourself a simple wrapper

```
name <- function(x, names){ setattr(x,'names', names)}


val <- 1:3
names <- LETTERS[1:3]
name(val, names)
# and it has worked!
val
## A B C 
## 1 2 3
```

Note that if you assign to a new object, both the old and new object will have the names!

Comment: Very interesting.   So you are saying that if I have an object that is 1GB in memory and I use `names<-` to change its name, that R will use another GB of memory to accomplish this?

Comment: Quite possibly, I wouldn't say always or for all object types, but especially for `data.frame` (and in the examples you posted) it did. See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13965103/1385941) (by a member of R core) which doesn't. The `data.table` package attempts to avoid much of the internal copying associated with data.frame.

Comment: +1 And there is `setnames` (lower case n) in `data.table`, too. That allows you to change particular names by name, easily; e.g. `setnames(DT,"oldbadname","New Nice Name")`.